# how to loadImage and draw the image without an error

Tags: javascript, image, loading, p5.js

im trying to load an image with p5.js `loadImage(image);`.
Im using the p5 library on my desktop.
Im not using the browser editor when im using the browser editor it handles the loading just fine

but im getting 2 errors the first one says

```
Fetch API cannot load 
file:///C:/Users/3worl/OneDrive/Skrivebord/G_O_E/planet.jpg. URL scheme 
must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

the second one says

```
p5.js:65680 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is pretty explicit:

> Fet API cannot load `file:///C://.....` URL scheme must be "http" or "https"

You are trying to access a file like you would do in the window file explorer with the path `file:///C://...` which doesn't work in javascript code.

If you look at the [`loadImage()` doc](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) you'll read:

> **The path to the image should be relative to the HTML file that links in your sketch.** Loading an image from a URL or other remote location may be blocked due to your browser's built-in security.

So let's say that your sketch is located on `C:/Users/3worl/OneDrive/Skrivebord/G_O_E/sketch.js` and your image on `C:/Users/3worl/OneDrive/Skrivebord/G_O_E/assets/planet.jpg` you will need to use `loadImage('assets/planet.jpg')` i.e. using the path of the image relative to the sketch.

Note that if you could also use an URL if the image is hosted online, like `loadImage('https://earthsky.org/upl/2018/01/planet-artist.jpg')` but that require that you host your image online which will require a webserver or an hosting service.